# iPhone Cocoa hyperlink

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, hyperlink

is there a way to display a hyperlink in an iPhone native app.  Is this done with a label or another UI object?

Thanks!
Joe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [Three20](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20) TTStyledText class

Answer (score 3):

Create a custom UIButton with only text (no background image) and write an IBAction on its click - you have a hyperlink...

Answer (score 1):

You can embed your text along with hyper link mark ups in a uiwebview object via a static HTML file. Another way is to show the link text on a uibutton and upon click of that button open safari to navigate to the link

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following solution: Display the htperlink text as a label and put a detailed disclusure button after it. (Detailed disclosure button is an arrowhead in a circle (>). Set the button title to the url, and make an IBAction that handle the click of the button. In this action you can create a new UIWebView, display it and load the URL into it.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually built-in support for this with a UITextView.  Check out the accepted answer to this stackoverflow question: [How to add hyperlink in iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407492/how-to-add-hyperlink-in-iphone-app)