# How to add hyperlink in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, hyperlink

In my iPhone app, I require to show the hyperlink to a website

How can I add hyperlink for a website in iPhone programming?.

Actually i want to pass the link from my app onto facebook using facebook API.

So how should I format my text such that it works as hyperlink on facebook?

I am still stuck with this issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends on where you want to put this link.
If it is in a UITextView, you just have to enable it.

```
textView.text = @"Some text with link in it : http://http://stackoverflow.com";
textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
```

More info on [iOS reference library](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1495/_index.html).

Or, if you want to open Safari programmatically:

```
NSURL *url = [ [ NSURL alloc ] initWithString: @"http://stackoverflow.com" ];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
[url release];
```

If you want to share on Facebook, you need to tell Safari to open a URL which will display a Facebook page that allows the user to share. Here is an example:

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://stackoverflow.com";
//The url you want to share

NSString *title = "The Title of the Page";
//The title you want to be displayed on Facebook

NSString *shareUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=%@&t=%@", urlString , title];
//Create the URL string which will tell Facebook you want to share that specific page 

NSURL *url = [ [ NSURL alloc ] initWithString:shareUrlString ];
//Create the URL object 

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
//Launch Safari with the URL you created

[url release];
//Release the object if you don't need it
```

Comment: Actually i want to pass the link from my app onto facebook using facebook API. So how should I format my text such that it works as hyperlink on facebook?

Comment: Ok, that's different. So you have a link you want users to be able to share on their Facebook profile ?

Comment: Isn't it answering your question ?

Comment: @Julien: Sorry I forgot to tick your answer as an answer. Really Sorry for that :)

Comment: @PARTH no problem :) 3 month is a decent amount of time to figure out if an answer is correct :p

Comment: Actually I forgot to tick your answer. I have around 151 questions now so I was just going through each question and realized that I didnt tick yours as an answer.Really Sorry for that and Thanks for being patient

Comment: How can I display a hyperLink on a UILabel. ?

Answer (score 2):

Drag a textView in your View Controller and select it's attribute inspector:

1. Set your text as "My website: www.mywebsitelink.com" and make sure
   that text type should be plain.
2. Tick your behavior as Selectable and not Editable.
3. Tick on detection as Links.

Run your project. You can see link in View Controller. Click on link, that will take you to safari and open a new tab on it.

Answer (score 1):

Parth

Can you mention where you need to insert `hyperlink` ,this is my way to insert `link` in iPhone app:

```
         NSMutableString *err=[[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        [err appendString:@"<html><body style=\"background-color:black\" ><font size=3 face=\"helvetica\" color=\"white\" align=\"center\"><H3>Login Error</H3><p> "];
        [err appendString:@"Please try again. If you forgot your password, you can retrieve it at<a href=\"ENTER YOUR LINK URL\"><font color=\"red\"> ENTER LINK TEXT</font></a>.</font></p></body></html>"];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My favorite library for sharing would be ShareKit.  It's really easy to setup in your app, and will allow people to share via Facebook, and other services too.  It's customizable too, so you can skin it, change colors, and control which services you want users to share with.

Check out, http://www.getsharekit.com/

Once you add it to your app you can integrate it very easily by creating a button

```
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction
 target:self
 action:@selector(share)];

//add the button to a navigation bar or tool bar.
```

and then creating the share method in your controller.

```
- (void)share
{
    // Create the item to share (in this example, a url)
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://getsharekit.com"];
    SHKItem *item = [SHKItem URL:url title:@"ShareKit is Awesome!"];

    // Get the ShareKit action sheet
    SHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];

    // Display the action sheet
    [actionSheet showFromToolbar:navigationController.toolbar];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

extension NSAttributedString{

add a new swift file for adding link in ios

```
  static func makeHyperlink(for path: String, in string: String, as substring: String) -> NSAttributedString {
    let nsString = NSString(string: string)
    let substringRange = nsString.range(of: substring)
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string)
    attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: path, range: substringRange)
    return attributedString
}
```

}

And then use this makehyperlink function in your text view function.

let attributedString = NSAttributedString.makeHyperlink(for: link, in: paragraph, as: "text to use for link")